# Can a python module read variables from the main program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just started learning python, and I like the language. I have a quick question I'm hoping you can answer (forgive my stupidity, I am still learning Python). How can I program a module to read variables from the program that imported it? If example.py says

```
import mymodule    
example = raw_input(' this is an example ')
```

how can I how can I program mymodule to read the value of `example`?

Does it not require any programming, and, in mymodule's source can I just type

```
print (example)
```

or is there code I have to use so that my module can get a value of a variable in the program that imported it?

P.S. I am brand new to python, and this is my first stackoverflow post, so please forgive my stupidity on what is no doubt a simple question. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions in your module should be able to take in arguments.  Then you can simply pass the `example` variable as a parameter.

E.g in mymodule.py:

```
def foo(x):
    print(x)
```

In your example.py:

```
import mymodule    
example = raw_input(' this is an example ')
mymodule.foo(example)
```